# Sending multiple attachments using Mutt command in Unix

Tags: mutt

I am facing an issue while sending multiple attachments using mutt command in UNIX. Currently, I am using the following code to send a single attachment.

`cat Count_Validation_Results_date +%m%d%Y.txt | mutt -a "/opt/sandbox/log_file_dir/Count_Validation_Session_$timeStamp.log" -s "Count Validation Test Comparison Results" USER1@XYZ.COM`

And if I use the following code, its not attaching the file that it was supposed to attach. Am I missing anything? Any help is really appreciated.

Here's is the email attachment

[image]

`cat Count_Validation_Results_date +%m%d%Y.txt | mutt -a "/opt/sandbox/log_file_dir/Count_Validation_Session_$timeStamp.log" -a "/export/home/x219325/log_file_dir/Count_Validation_Error_$timeStamp.log" -s "Count Validation Test Comparison Results" USER1@XYZ.COM`

Answer (score 1):

From mutt man page:

```
-a file [...]
   Attach  a  file  to  your  message  using  MIME.  When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient
   addresses with "--" is mandatory, e.g. mutt -a image.jpg -- addr1 or mutt -a img.jpg *.png -- addr1  addr2.   The  -a  option
   must be placed at the end of command line options.
```

So, you don't need the `-a` flag for each attached file, but **you must** add the `--` separator before the recipients.

Also option ordering is important. You must send the subject option to the front.